# How to delegate Identity from Web-Application to WebAPI

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, jwt, openid-connect, bearer-token

I am trying to build a website, where the user logs in at the and can use an backend web-API.

Calls to the backend web-API will always be proxied by the frontend website, since the backend is not publicly available.
Back- and frontend are MVC 6 (or MVC Core?) projects based on ASP.net Core.

The frontend currently authenticates (successfully) by using OpenId-Connect.
The backend should use JwtBearerToken.

The authentication so far requests the response type is `id_token code` and the scope is `openid profile`.

After the roundtrip to the Auth-Server (ADFS 2016), I will end up in the `AuthorizationCodeReceived`-Event from ASP.NET, but I have no luck in exchanging the code for authorization token. I tried the following using ADAL:

```
public override async Task AuthorizationCodeReceived(AuthorizationCodeReceivedContext context)
        {
            await base.AuthorizationCodeReceived(context);

            var clientCredential = new ClientCredential(context.Options.ClientId, context.Options.ClientSecret);

            var oAuthContext = new AuthenticationContext(context.Options.Authority, false);
            var oAuthResult = await oAuthContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(context.Code, new Uri(context.RedirectUri), clientCredential);
        }
```

I had to disable the authority validation (which I do not like) and I do not get results other than Http-Status 400.
I'd be happy for any advice how to move on.

**Update**
Further Investigation Shows, that the OpenIdConnect-Configuration allows to save auth and refresh Tokens into the Claims. Nevertheless I don't see the possibility to convert it in the first place.
I also tried exchanging the code by hand (PS: `Invoke-WebRequest` ...) but had no success. Perhaps this is a problem of ADFS TP4...

Comment: As of ASP.Net Core RC2, this works automatically.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to get this scenario to work with TP4.

```
AuthorizationCodeReceived = async n =>
{
   string code = n.Code;

   AuthenticationContext ac = new AuthenticationContext(BaseAddress, false);
   ClientCredential client = new ClientCredential("clientid", "secret");
   string resourceId = "https://myservices/myapi";
   AuthenticationResult ar = await ac.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(code, new Uri("https://localhost:44300/"), client, resourceId);
}
```

You can then use the access token from a controller method like this:

```
AuthenticationContext ac = new AuthenticationContext(Startup.BaseAddress, false);
ClientCredential cred = new ClientCredential("clientid", "secret");
string resourceId = "https://myservices/myapi";
AuthenticationResult ar = ac.AcquireTokenSilent(resourceId, cred, UserIdentifier.AnyUser);


var client = new HttpClient();
client.SetBearerToken(ar.AccessToken);

var result = await client.GetStringAsync("http://localhost:2727/identity");
```

Comment: Hm.. that looks familiar - can you add Information, what BaseAddress is here?

Comment: As of RC2, OpenIdConnect from Asp.Net Core, will do this automatically